# background should start after background

Tags: html, css, background

I have the problem that my background image covers another background. I want that the 2nd background should start after the image not from the top of the site where the 1st image starts. If I add positioning to the 2nd image it works but is there a solution without positioning?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 50) {
    $('div#myTopnav').addClass('scrolled');
    $('a').addClass('scrolled2');
  } else {
    $('div#myTopnav ').removeClass('scrolled');
    $('a').removeClass('scrolled2');
  }
});

function myFunction() {
  $("#myTopnav").toggleClass('responsive');

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 2000px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1000px;
}

.topnav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  transition: 0.35s all ease;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 50px;
  ;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.35s all ease;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1001;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 1001;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a:hover {
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: white;
  }
}

.banner {
  background: url('/images/camera2.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  z-index: 120;
  position: absolute;
}

#grad {
  background: red;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ecd8c6, white);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#ecd8c6, white);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#ecd8c6, white);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#ecd8c6, white);
  /* Standard syntax */
  height: 60%;
  position: relative;
  top: 920px;
  left: 0;
}

.scrolled {
  min-height: 10px;
  color: inherit;
  background: black;
  transition: 0.35s all ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.scrolled2 {
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav" align="left">
  <a href="">
    <p>Home</p>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <p>Portfolio</p>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <p>About</p>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <p>Impressum</p>
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
<div class="banner topnav"></div>
<div id="grad">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but what should i add? @Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i guess you want the `grad`  to start arfter the `banner`. first, why does `.banner` also have class `.topnav` ?  ( it will get the styles from `.topnav` also ) . plus, does `banner` need to have `position:absolute`?

well if `banner` has to have position absolute, and i see you gave `min-height:100vh` to it, and you want `grad` to start right after it, why don't you set `top:100vh` ( equal to banner height ) on `grad` ?

so you will have

```
  #grad {
  background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ecd8c6, white); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#ecd8c6, white); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#ecd8c6, white); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#ecd8c6, white); /* Standard syntax */
  height: 60%;
  position: relative;
  top: 100vh;
  left: 0;
  }
```

see snippet or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/DTcHh/32864/)

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 50) {
     $('div#myTopnav').addClass('scrolled');
     $('a').addClass('scrolled2');
   } else {
     $('div#myTopnav ').removeClass('scrolled');
     $('a').removeClass('scrolled2');
   }
 });

 function myFunction() {
   $("#myTopnav").toggleClass('responsive');

 }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 2000px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1000px;
}

.topnav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  transition: 0.35s all ease;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 50px;
  ;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.35s all ease;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(: first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1001;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 1001;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a:hover {
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: white;
  }
}

.banner {
  background: url('/images/camera2.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  z-index: 120;
  position: absolute;
}

#grad {
  background: red;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ecd8c6, white);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#ecd8c6, white);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#ecd8c6, white);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#ecd8c6, white);
  /* Standard syntax */
  height: 60%;
  position: relative;
  top: 100vh;
  left: 0;
}

.scrolled {
  min-height: 10px;
  color: inherit;
  background: black;
  transition: 0.35s all ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.scrolled2 {
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav" align="left">
  <a href="">
    <p>Home</p>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <p>Portfolio</p>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <p>About</p>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <p>Impressum</p>
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
<div class="banner topnav"></div>
<div id="grad">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```